# Naming convention for weeks

Tags: time

We have names for days in a week and for months in a year, but does a convention exist for weeks in the month? Alternatively, do we have names for weeks in the year other than, say, "The 34th week of 2018"?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, no. Just like there are names for the weekdays, but there are no names for the days of a month (the 17th of the month is just the 17th of the month).

Comment: The Egyptian/Coptic calendar had and has names for each of the three 10-day weeks of the standard months plus a name for the 5 or 6 extra days thrown in at the end.

Comment: In the Gregorian calendar, the "naming system" is precisely what you said: "the 1st week in August", "the 17th week of 2018", &c. This shows up in the formal descriptions of some holidays, like the American Thanksgiving celebration. *The Farmer's Almanac* & co. might still say sth like "the 1st week of summer", "the 3rd week after the April rains", &c. but they're not in very common use.

Comment: You may see some weeks given names in religious calendars - "Easter Week", "Holy Week",  etc. - but those are only in limited use.

Comment: No, very clearly we do not. 

Ignoring both logic and language, I happen to have spent most of the last 10 years in retail where even when bean-counters think there's a need for something else, real people understand there is not.

Most of the “problem” is that of course we have names for days in a week and months in a year, almost no-one I concerned about weeks in the month and why would he, please?

What suggests we might have names for weeks in the year other than, say, “… 34th …”?

Comment: What a funny question. Certainly if we had a convention for naming the weeks, you wouldn't need to ask if it existed. It would be a convention.

Answer (score 2):

If you really wanted to have a system for this, for Catholics or the traditionally-minded religious,

## the [liturgical octaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octave_(liturgy))

are specially named weeks throughout the year. (The term “octave” is misleading to us moderns. They’re reckoned as lasting eight days *by counting inclusively* in the ancient Roman manner: i.e., they’re actually 7 days long.) The big ones are the [octaves of Easter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octave_of_Easter), Epiphany, and Christmas although there are 15 other specially-handled weeks as well.

This obviously has very little pull in the general secular system, even if it is named after a pope. Even the Church itself generally thinks in terms of [Eastertide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastertide) (50 days) and [Christmastide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmastide) (12 days) rather than the octaves in its general planning.

Comment: The liturgical "octaves" are certain 7-day periods with specific names. They are not divisions of the year, do not extend over the entire year and are not contiguous.

Comment: @Kris That's all covered in the answer already. It's the closest to what they're asking about, though, so there's no real explanation for the downvotes.

Comment: While I didn't downvote, I agree that this isn't useful to the OP, who asks for a convention, whereas *octave* would only work as a facetious or literary novelty term. It is somewhat akin to suggesting the term *solemnity* for your grandmother's 80th birthday.